# ASP.NET Core middleware handling request/response bodies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I am playing around with the powers of middleware in ASP.NET Core.

I replaced all my try/catch statements in favor for a global exception handling middleware.

It has the tasks to handle all uncaught exceptions (log them, return 500 Internal Server Error response) but should also handle all manually created results with status code 500.

I am testing against this controller:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class TestController : ControllerBase
  {

    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
      return "hello";
    }

    [HttpPost("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Post(int id)
    {
      throw new Exception("test exception");
    }

    [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id)
    {
      return StatusCode(500, "this information may contains sensitive data");
    }

  }
```

The skeleton of my middleware so far looks like:

```
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  private readonly ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> _logger;

  private LogLevel LogLevel { get; } = LogLevel.Error;
  private bool EnforceEmptyResult { get; } = true;

  public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> logger)
  {
      _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
      _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
  }

  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
  {

    try
    {
      await _next(httpContext);

      // handles the internal server error responses
      if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
      {
        await LogError(httpContext, LogLevel);
        //if (EnforceEmptyResult) await ClearResponseBody(httpContext.Response);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // handles the uncaught exceptions
      await LogException(httpContext, ex, LogLevel);
      await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, (!EnforceEmptyResult) ? ex : null);
    }
  }

  public Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
  {
    if (exception == null)
    {
      // the basic error response (500, no body, no content type)
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
      context.Response.ContentType = null;
      return context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
      // the error response with the exception as plain text
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      return context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.ToString());
    }
  }

  public async Task LogException(HttpContext context, Exception exception, LogLevel logLevel)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("exception occured");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    sb.Append("request body");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(await RequestBody(context.Request));
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("---");

    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("response body");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(await ResponseBody(context.Response));
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("---");

    _logger.Log(logLevel, exception, sb.ToString());
  }

  public async Task LogError(HttpContext context, LogLevel logLevel)
  {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("error occured");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    sb.Append("request body");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(await RequestBody(context.Request));
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("---");

    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("response body");
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(await ResponseBody(context.Response));
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append("---");

    _logger.Log(logLevel, sb.ToString());
  }

  public async Task<string> RequestBody(HttpRequest request)
  {
    if (!request.ContentLength.HasValue || request.ContentLength.Value <= 0) return null;

    var requestBody = request.Body;

    request.EnableRewind();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[request.ContentLength.Value];

    await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    request.Body = requestBody;

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
  }

  public async Task<string> ResponseBody(HttpResponse response)
  {
    if (!response.ContentLength.HasValue || response.ContentLength.Value <= 0) return null;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[response.ContentLength.Value];

    await response.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
  }

  public async Task ClearResponseBody(HttpResponse response)
  {
    response.ContentType = null;
    await response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
  }
}
```

I have a few issues with it relating to the handling of the bodies of the request/response.

In `public async Task<string> RequestBody(HttpRequest request)` I am using EnableRewind because a tutorial suggested it. I am not sure if I need it or not in that case. Fortunately so far it works and I see the body in the logs.

Am I using it correcly?

The `public async Task<string> ResponseBody(HttpResponse response)` seems to not work, since I newer see the response body. I want to display what is included in the response so far (may there are partial results) or in the case of returning status code 500 with an error message I want to log this error message.

How do I get the response body?

Using the `public async Task ClearResponseBody(HttpResponse response)` method throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.

How to manipulate the body of the response to avoid leaking of may sensitive development data?

And a minor detail on the side is that it seems I use the exception middleware in the wrong spot within the pipeline. I added it as the first entry right on the top of the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method.

This seems to be potentionally wrong because in case of an uncaught exception I do not only get the logs of my middleware but also logs like:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Sample2.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Sample2.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> test exception

Comment: *“I want to display what is included in the response so far”* – Unless there is something wrong during the output generation (which I would say is rather rare), the response body is never being written to, especially so that you can still modify response headers. Exceptions e.g. within the MVC middleware are usually thrown early so that there isn’t a response yet. – *“How to manipulate the  body of the response to avoid leaking sensitive development data?”* – The body shouldn’t contain this in the first place, so you shouldn’t actually need to do anything to filter something out.

Comment: I agree there shouldn't be any sensitive data in the response anyway. But I wanted to ensure that status code 500 responses are always have empty body without content type and may use the body to transport messages to the exception middleware.